# Gaps between adjacent light rays from a light source

Tags: visible-light

I can not seem to grasp light rays FILLING space like air and liquid in an enclosure. 
Two rays adjacent to each other coming from Sun, - do they not diverge as they go into space? If so is there not dark space gap between them, constantly increasing? How come when the sun is up in the sky, we do not perceive these dark spaces as night, as we travel around the sun while facing it, like an interference pattern? I hope my Q is clear.

Comment: You are right that the intensity of light from a source decreases with distance; see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law) and [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/39416/is-the-number-of-rays-projected-by-a-source-of-light-finite?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: This is probably covered in the links Ziggurat provided, but instead of light, think of the heat from the sun. This is felt all over your body and the land around you,  with no gaps unless something causes a shade. This heat is the same type of radiation as light, so rather than thinking of discrete rays, think of a continuous field.

Answer (score 0):

The photon density for 1370 Watts per square meter is high enough that there are no gaps. If we move far enough away, the the photons are few and far between--except one must account for the Hanbury-Brown Twiss effect--which would manifest as "gap filling" correlations. Weird.